# SQLAlchemy model constraints across multiple models

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to figure out the best way to develop constraints around a set of models

```py
class ParentDefinition:
    child_definition = relationship()

class ChildDefinition:
    parent_definition_id = ForeignKey()

class Parent:
    parent_definition = relationship()
    parent_definition_id = ForeignKey()

class Child:
    parent = relationship()
    parent_id = ForeignKey()

    child_definition = relationship()
    child_definition_id = ForeignKey()
```

I want to ensure that `Child.child_definition_id == Child.parent.parent_definition.child_definition.id` but I'm not sure the best way to do that.

I know that this probably isn't the best model design but there are pre-existing architecture considerations I'm working around.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/constraints.html#unique-constraint) you need to define constraint to a table or a column. As far as I know, SQL constraints can't be setup over multiple table.

If you really want to go through constraints, you can use another table that handle the association between each entities constrainable fields (ids of each items and add your constraint to id_parent_def = id_child_def).

If you don't want to create this table, you can always use [listeners](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.before_insert) so you can check before inserting data but this may be inefficient for your needs.

Another way would to use database specific functions or triggers that could check conditions for you, I guess you would write  plain SQL inside your migrations file to create them (or manually in your DB).